# Is there a real and relevant relationship between Big Bang and dark matter?

Tags: big-bang, dark-matter

Since the postulate of dark matter is based on the unexpected rotational velocity around the centre of a spiral galaxy, then it can be presumed that the Big Bang Theory is not relevant to the search for WIMPs, axions or even the Higg's boson. If this is correct, then why does the Big Bang Theory appear to be so much related to the presence or absence of dark matter, at least in popular thinking?

Comment: Dark energy has had a bearing on universal evolution - might you be confusing the two?

Comment: Not sure that there's sufficient difference between the two, in that, if dark energy has had a bearing on universal evolution, then presumably dark matter has as well because of the close relationship between the two.

Comment: There's no relationship between the two, though. They're completely different things.

Comment: Dark energy has been postulated since dark matter, and appears to be occupying minds more and more as dark matter remains undetected. But Big Bang has been around for longer than both, has it not?

Comment: I'm not clear how it is that energy and matter, whether dark or visible, can be completely different things.

Comment: Check out the Wikipedia articles on the two. The theory of dark energy, in its current form, is decades younger than dark matter. Energy and matter are the same, sure, but you wouldn't say that a unit of energy is the same as a quark, would you?

Comment: Agree with @HDE226868 the only direct relationship between dark matter and dark energy is the word "dark".

Comment: One easy way to see the differences is that dark matter has perfectly Newtonian consequences on galactic (and probably even the solar system) scale, while dark energy only makes sense on the cosmological scale as part of a cosmology based entirely on general relativity.

Answer (score 0):

*Dark matter/energy is related to the Big Bang* but probably not as much as your popular thinking implies (don't really know what you're referring to).

So let me explain the link. Most people know dark matter solves missing gravity in galaxy's. However this is only the first and most obvious clue that led to dark matter. Another one is key to inflation cosmology, the modern/improved version of the Big Bang theory.

To understand this we must look at a puzzling question: [what is the shape of the universe?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_of_the_universe) Apart from it having to be symmetrical, general relativity implies that the amount of matter would curve space-time: so if the average matter density in the universe is more than the density parameter it would be spherical (positive curve). If it's equal to the parameter, the universe is flat, and less means a hyperbolic universe (negative curve). Details aside, if the average density in the universe differed from the density parameter, the inflation of the universe would have exploded that difference. If it was off by a tiny fraction, the difference would know be in the factor of trillions. However measurements show the value has to be very close to the density parameter.

So the Big Bang predicts the amount of mass in the universe pretty accurately, and guess what? Where 96% short. Exactly as much as dark matter and energy combined. So yeah, **inflation predicts dark matter**. This is why dark matter and energy is such an important question, different theories predict them.